# Google sheets - Search and bring as list and paste it to next empty row

Tags: search, google-sheets, row, paste, is-empty

I need your help to create a list of search results.

I have a list of search items (over 10.000 items ) as you can see on screenshot column B.

I wrote a function to bring result from main list (on Sheet DM1).
=QUERY('DM1'!$C$4:$J$12874,"select * where G LIKE '%"&B3&"%' ",1)

It works fine. But I need to add all the search result (which always include more than one row mostly 4-5 rows and consist of 8 columns) after each other without empty cells between.

So basically according to my search results I would like to make (continuous) another complete list which consist of 8 columns.

How can I do that on google sheets?

If there is a way to filter my main list on DM1 sheet with the values from my search list in another way that works for me also.

[Column B Search list, Column C to J is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeccY.png)

@ale13 hey, The screenshot shows search result for only "14Q02". And following items on the list (column B) needs to be copied right under it.

My formula copies with titles { I do not need that after first search item so formula could be  =QUERY('DM1'!$C$4:$J$12874,"select * where G LIKE '%"&B3&"%' ",0) }

Here is the screenshot (I only added second item search result which is "14Q04".)

[Here is the screenshot (I only added second items search result which is "14Q04") together with first item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1R2E.png)

[Sample file is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M0bhy3CMCzj7OiOsw6pjKVg4JAPaucTplb3VHTrp2L4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey there, do you also have a screenshot which pictures the desired result in this situation? @Engin

Comment: Hi @ale13, added screenshot

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet, rather than just the screenshots, to facilitate seeing your desired outcome, and to allow others to more easily work on your question, as recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  The sheet, with sample data only, should be shared and editable by all.

Comment: @kirkg13, you are right. I added sample file link.

Comment: So essentially you want to retrieve all the details for all the tags and transfer them to the other sheet? @EnginT

Comment: @ale13 , I want to bring results from DM1 sheet, for only listed tags on column B in sheet1 and paste them to the sheet1 as in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two possible approaches, depending on how many listed tags you might have in column B of Sheet1.  If it is only going to be up to ten or so, you could do something like this:

```
=QUERY(DM1!C4:J12,"select * where G <> '' and (G = '"&B3&"' OR G = '"&B4&"' OR G = '"&B5&"' OR G = '"&B6&"' OR G = '"&B7&"' OR G = '"&B8&"' OR G = '"&B9&"') ",1)
```

The second approach, perhaps more elegant, is building the query dynamically like this:

```
=QUERY('DM1'!$C$4:$J$12,"select * where G <> ''" & CONCATENATE(A3:A99),1)
```

Then in A3 (or in some other hidden helper column if preferred) you place this formula:

```
={"AND G='" & B3 & "'";ArrayFormula(if(len(B4:B),"OR G = '"&B4:B&"' ",""))}
```

This ends up with the same formula as earlier, but it dynamically adds the following text to the QUERY for each listed tag in column B.
`OR G = 'tag-value'` .

I've added a sample tab, Sheet1-GK, on your sheet to demonstrate this.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thank you very much.
Your second approach works better. Because I have thousands of rows to search on many different sheets. Your help is much appreciated.